# Load a callback function before html angular

Tags: angular, recaptcha

Here is my captcha derivative

```
<div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="my_site_key" data-callback="myCallback"></div>
```

Here is my callback defined in constructor

```
constructor(
private router: Router,
private route: ActivatedRoute
) {
  this.onloadCallback = () => {console.log(grecaptcha.getResponse());}
}
```

I am getting error

> ReCAPTCHA couldn't find user-provided function: myCallback.

Please tell me how can I define myCallback function before loading of html.

Comment: Re-captcha does not understand Angular template, it is just pure javascript. The callback should be available in the global scope

Comment: Is this what you are saying.. window.oncallback = () => {console.log(grecaptcha.getResponse());}